# What is difference in -5 and numbers smaller than -5 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've just started to learn so i was just messing in interpreter and found some weird outputs that I couldn't understand. This is what I did and what i got:

```
c = -5
c is -5
True

c = -6
c is -6
False
```

This happened for all values smaller(more negative) than -5.
What am I missing?

Here's a 
[screenshot of interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0v38.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the differences between "is" and "=="

You can see this addressed here [Is there a difference between "==" and "is"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is)